# Definition doesn't change the variable

Tags: python

For some reason `Money` doesn't change to 8 as it should; it always stays at 10.

```
Money = 10
Resto = 0
ApplePrice = 2


def buy(current, price):
    Money == current - price
    return Money

buy(Money, ApplePrice)
print(Money)
```

Comment: Money in your function knows nothing about the Money outside

Comment: @PadraicCunningham Agreed that the dupe is right, but just another thing, it should be this:  `Money = current - price` which may confuse the OP.

Comment: Your function has a return value ... you should set a variable for accept that return value

Comment: `Money == current - price` is wrong from two perspectives. One is the use of == vs =.  Your function drops the value of `Money == current-price`(a boolean)  on the bit floor. Even if you fix that, it will not do what you think it should do.

Comment: @Zizouz212.  True but that is most likely a typo, changing to `=` is not going to change the Money variable outside the function which is what the OP expects

Comment: @CedricH., it is 100 percent about the scope of the variables.

Comment: @CedricH. This has everything to do with globals... If there was an understand of that, then the OP would've figured this out already. Padraic, true. You've got a point.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rather than altering the global variable I'd recommend keeping your variables as they are & using the return value from `buy()`;

```
money = buy(MONEY, APPLEPRICE)
print(money)
```

You've also got a problem with the calculation in the function.

You would want this, defining your [constants](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#constants) first.

```
MONEY = 10
RESTO = 0
APPLEPRICE = 2

def buy(current, price):
    money = current - price
    return money

money = buy(MONEY, APPLEPRICE)
print(money)
```

I know docs aren't that interesting, but take a look over [PEP8](http://legacy.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#naming-conventions) as it will help you write good code to a standard most of us try to match.

Comment: This is wrong. Look at the first line of the `buy` function. You're evaluating an expression, not an assignment (which I assume is what you're trying to do. This won't solve anything.

Comment: @Zizouz212 that doesn't make my original point wrong. It just means there's more than one problem.

Comment: Seriously, please read the code.

Comment: Using `MONEY` as a global variable whose value changes goes very much against the grain of PEP8. A thing with an all-caps name (e.g., `CONSTANT`, or `MONEY`) should be constant!